# How to find the webpage loading time using cocoa touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am doing an application which has to display the WebPage loading time as a msg. Can anyone please help me to find the loading time?

Thanks,
kabilan

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your `UIWebViewDelegate`, measure the time difference between `-webViewDidStartLoad:` and `-webViewDidFinishLoad:`